# Dexguard error : A RASP callback com.app_test.dexguard.RaspCallback.dgRaspCallback was specified, but the specification didn't match any method

Tags: flutter, dart, security, proguard, dexguard

`com.guardsquare.dexguard.bkS: A RASP callback com.app_test.dexguard.RaspCallback.dgRaspCallback was specified, but the specification didn't match any method. Please check your configuration. at com.guardsquare.dexguard.cLE.c(DexGuard9.5.0-beta07:8253) at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183) at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195) at java.base/java.util.HashMap$ValueSpliterator.forEachRemaining(HashMap.java:1693) at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150) at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173) at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497) at com.guardsquare.dexguard.cLE.e(DexGuard9.5.0-beta07:158) at com.guardsquare.dexguard.dBv.d(DexGuard9.5.0-beta07:32) at com.guardsquare.dexguard.bkQ.main(DexGuard9.5.0-beta07:32030)`

========================================================

This is my config "dexguard-project.txt"

```
-raspchecks apptamper, root, debug, emulator, hook, virtualenvironment, certificatetamper
-raspcontinueon root
-raspclassfilter class com.app_test.dexguard.RaspCallback
-raspcallback class com.app_test.dexguard.RaspCallback {
    public static void dgRaspCallback(com.guardsquare.dexguard.rasp.callback.DetectionReport);
}

-keepclassmembers class com.app_test.dexguard.RaspCallback { *; }
-keepclassmembernames class com.app_test.dexguard.RaspCallback { *; }
```